# github のフィンガープリントについて

Tags: git, github, ssh

サーバ上にて

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

とコマンドを打った時に

> RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.

と返ってきますがこれはgithub.comのフィンガ―プリントという認識で合っていますでしょうか。

githubの自分のリポジトリに登録したsshキーと違うものでしたので少し気になりまして質問させていただきました。

色々調べていたら[こちらのサイト](http://monsat.hatenablog.com/entry/generating-ssh-keys-for-github)を見つけ、全く同じフィンガープリントでしたので、ためしにyesで入ってみたら無事

> Hi!xxxxxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access

と表示されたのでgithub.comのフィンガープリントという考えに至りましたが、間違っていたらご指摘を頂けましたら幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 7):

その認識でよいです。

公式のヘルプにもそのフィンガープリントがありました。

https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！ssh、フィンガープリント共に触り始めたばかりで少々理解が薄く質問させていただきましたが勉強になりましたm(_)m